gradle shadowJar exclude transitive when using api()
Let's say I have the following gradle java projects:
Library:
dependencies {
    api("dep1")
    api("dep2")
    api("dep3")
}

Software-Api:
dependencies {
    api("library")
}

Software-Impl:
dependencies {
    implementation(project(":api")
}

The problem is that with shadowJar it includes every dependency declared with api().
I can declare Software-Impl as isTransitive = false, for this case. But that doesn't feel right?
Am I misunderstanding something about the use of api() ?
Should I avoid re-declaring dependencies as api() ?
Thanks in advance
